# jQuery event when select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the event to bind for when a select form is selected?

I have something like this:

```
<select id='list'>
<option value='1'>Option A</option>
<option value='2'>Option B</option>
<option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

When Option B is selected, I want some function to run.

So what do I bind,

```
$("#list").bind("?", function (){
// How do I check if it's option b that's selected here
//blah blah
});
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This jQuery snippet will get you started:

```
$('#list').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
        // Do something for option "b"
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of $('option:selected', this).val() you can just use $(this).val()

Comment: What about if option A is already selected by default? Such as in the OP's example. You wouldn't have a redirect if you selected option A.

Comment: @Pim: See answer from qraqatit below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71945665/8398149

Answer (score 5):

the event you are looking for is `change`. more info about that event is available in the jquery docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#fn

Comment: Works for just about all inputs ... IE misbehaves on radios I think.

Comment: yeah IE has a lot of problems with radios and checkboxes - least of all change... i use the click event for those two

Answer (score 1):

Although few years late, this actually works also if one select already selected option.

```
jQuery('#list').on('click', 'option', function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() === '2') {
        // Do something for option "b"
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe **select()** is a more accurated solution:

```
$('#list').select(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
        // Do something for option "b"
    }
});
```

Comment: "The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes."

https://api.jquery.com/select/