# calendar algorithm #javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can somebody help me with a calendar algorithm? How can I display the calendar with algorithm (using javascript)? Maybe somebody can copy my code and type inside?

**code:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

 <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    ul {list-style-type: none;}
    body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}

    .month {
        padding: 70px 25px;
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .month ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .month ul li {
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }

    .month .prev {
        float: left;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .month .next {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .weekdays {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .weekdays li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 13.6%;
        color: #666;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .days {
        padding: 10px 0;
        background: #eee;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .days li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 13.6%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size:12px;
        color: #777;
    }

    .days li .active {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #1abc9c;
        color: white !important
    }

    /* Add media queries for smaller screens */
    @media screen and (max-width:720px) {
        .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
        .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
        .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
        .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
```

**Month is working, year too**

```
Select Month:
    <select>
    <script>
        var maanden = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","Mei","Jun", "Jul", "Aug" 
         , 
          "Sep", "Okt", "Nov","Dec"];
          for( var i = 0; i <= 11; i++){
           document.write( ' <option value="+(m-1)+">' +maanden[i] + ' 
       </option>' )
           }
    </script>
    </select>

    Select Year
   <select>
   <script>
        for( var m = 2000; m <= 2017; m++){
        document.write( ' <option value="+(m-1)+">' +m + ' </option>' )
       }
   </script>
 </select>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print Calendar">

 <div class="month">
    <ul>
        <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
        <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
       <li>
           September<br>
            <span style="font-size:18px">2017</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays">
    <li>Zo</li>
    <li>Ma</li>
    <li>Di</li>
    <li>Wo</li>
    <li>Do</li>
    <li>Vr</li>
    li>Za</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
   <li>16</li>
   <li>17</li>
   <li>18</li>
   <li>19</li>
   <li>20</li>
   <li>21</li>
   <li>22</li>
   <li>23</li>
   <li>24</li>
   <li>25</li>
   <li>26</li>
   <li>27</li>
   <li>28</li>
   <li>29</li>
   <li>30</li>
 </ul>
 <script>
    var d = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you please specify what your question is exactly?

Comment: Ohh, if i want to put the date January, it need to display Januray or if i put the dat of a year ago it shows then January 2016

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the code you have here is only displaying the calendar. Can you please add your code dealing with the selection logic?

Comment: I don't understand the selection logic :P

Comment: Example: If you click on "Print Calendar" it shows the date en year you chooshed in the selection.

Comment: The procces to do that "display the date" with Javascript, i don't understand how to begin :P

Comment: do you use a calendar js library?

Comment: No, the calendar is hardcoded with HTML.

Comment: Then you might want to look at how to [process events when option is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535520/jquery-event-when-select-option)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery event when select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535520/jquery-event-when-select-option)